# Pandas: create new column in df with random integers from range

Tags: python, pandas, random, integer, range

I have a pandas data frame with 50k rows.  I'm trying to add a new column that is a randomly generated integer from 1 to 5.

If I want 50k random numbers I'd use:

```py
df1['randNumCol'] = random.sample(range(50000), len(df1))
```

but for this I'm not sure how to do it.

Side note in R, I'd do:

```r
sample(1:5, 50000, replace = TRUE)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In pandas/numpy, there is a direct function `np.random.randint(low, high, size)`. No need to actually generate the range `low:high` and sample from it, as we do in R.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

One solution is to use [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
import numpy as np
df1['randNumCol'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, df1.shape[0])
```

Or if the numbers are non-consecutive (albeit slower), you can use this:

```
df1['randNumCol'] = np.random.choice([1, 9, 20], df1.shape[0])
```

In order to make the results reproducible you can set the seed with [`numpy.random.seed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) (e.g. `np.random.seed(42)`)

Answer (score 36):

To add a column of random integers, use [`randint(low, high, size)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random%20randint#random.randint). There's no need to waste memory allocating `range(low, high)` which is what that used to do in Python 2.x; that could be a lot of memory if `high` is large.

```
df1['randNumCol'] = np.random.randint(0,5, size=len(df1))
```

Notes:

- when we're just adding a single column, `size` is just an integer. In general if we want to generate an array/dataframe of `randint()s`, size can be a *tuple*, as in [Pandas: How to create a data frame of random integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752292/pandas-how-to-create-a-data-frame-of-random-integers))
- [in Python 3.x `range(low, high)` no longer allocates a list (potentially using lots of memory), it produces a `range()` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571718/python-3-range-vs-python-2-range)
- use [`random.seed(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random%20randint#random.seed) beforehand, for determinism and reproducibility

Answer (score 5):

An option that doesn't require an additional import for numpy:

```py
df1['randNumCol'] = pd.Series(range(1,6)).sample(int(5e4), replace=True).array
```

Answer (score 1):

`randint` is fine to generate small arrays but for larger arrays, Numpy's random Generators such as `Generator.integers` is faster especially if the range of integers to choose from is large. To use it, construct the `numpy.random.default_rng()` and call the appropriate method e.g. `integers`, `choice`, `normal`, `standard_normal` etc. The following is an example where `len(df1)` number of pseudo-random integers between 1 and 4 are generated and assigned to a column.

```py
import numpy as np

df1['randNumCol'] = np.random.default_rng().integers(1, 5, len(df1))
```

For a reproducible array of numbers, you can set a random seed in the generator in the same line:

```py
df1['randNumCol'] = np.random.default_rng(2023).integers(1, 5, len(df1))
#                                         ^^^^  <--- set seed here
```

If the range starts from 0 or if the range is not consecutive, then `Generator.choice` could be used (and it is much faster than `choice`):

```py
# sample from numbers from 0 to 4
rng = np.random.default_rng()
df1['randNumCol'] = rng.choice(5, len(df1))

# sample from the given list
df1['randNumCol'] = rng.choice([1, 2, 4], len(df1))
```

As the following timeit test shows, `Generator.integers` is about 60% faster than `randint`.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(100_000_000))

%timeit df1['randNumCol'] = np.random.randint(1, 50, len(df1))
# 1.43 s ± 23.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df1['randNumCol'] = np.random.default_rng().integers(1, 50, len(df1))
# 886 ms ± 31.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10 loops each)
```