# How to create a DataFrame of random integers with Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I know that if I use [`randn`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html), the following code gives me what I am looking for, but with elements from a normal distribution. But what if I just wanted random integers?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

`randint` works by providing a range, but not an array like `randn`. So how do I do this with random integers between some range?

Comment: And related for when we're just adding a column: [Pandas: create new column in df with random integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327417/python-create-new-column-in-pandas-df-with-random-numbers-from-range)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

[`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) accepts a third argument (`size`) , in which you can specify the size of the output array. You can use this to create your `DataFrame` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Here - `np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4))` - creates an output array of size `(100,4)` with random integer elements between `[0,100)` .

---

Demo -

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

which produces:

```
     A   B   C   D
0   45  88  44  92
1   62  34   2  86
2   85  65  11  31
3   74  43  42  56
4   90  38  34  93
5    0  94  45  10
6   58  23  23  60
..  ..  ..  ..  ..
```

Comment: Question: Why does this work? What function is being called by `pandas.DataFrame(x, y)` when x is a `numpy.ndarray` (which in this case is a 2d matrix like thing)?

Answer (score 24):

The recommended way to create random integers with NumPy these days is to use `numpy.random.Generator.integers`. ([documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.integers.html#numpy.random.Generator.integers))

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df
----------------------
      A    B    C    D
 0   58   96   82   24
 1   21    3   35   36
 2   67   79   22   78
 3   81   65   77   94
 4   73    6   70   96
... ...  ...  ...  ...
95   76   32   28   51
96   33   68   54   77
97   76   43   57   43
98   34   64   12   57
99   81   77   32   50
100 rows × 4 columns
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`np.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().choice(100, size=(100, 4)), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

The advantage of this method over `integers` is that you can choose from any list / array you want. For example, if you want to generate random sample from `[2, 5, 10]`, then

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().choice([2,5,10], size=(100, 4)), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

You can even associate a probability distribution to sample entries. For example, if you want to choose 2 with p=0.8, and 5 with p=0.2, you can do so by, passing `p=` argument.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().choice([2,5], p=[.8,.2], size=(100, 4)), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

---

Also, with the `Generator`, `choice` is as fast as `integers` and faster than `randint`.

```py
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().choice(100, size=(100_000,4)), columns=[*'ABCD'])
# 3.34 ms ± 308 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 100, size=(100_000,4)), columns=[*'ABCD'])
# 3.81 ms ± 708 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100_000,4)), columns=[*'ABCD'])
# 6.78 ms ± 776 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```