# Exported and imported DataFrames differ but should be the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import, export-to-csv

I tried to import some data from an Excel file to a pandas DataFrame, convert it into a csv file and read it back in (need to do some further file based handling on that exported csv file later on, so that is a necessary step).

For the sake of data integrity, exported and re-imported data should be the same. So, I compared the different DataFrames and encountered, that these are not the same, at least according to pandas' [`.equals()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html).

I thought this might be an issue related to string encoding when exporting and re-importing the data since I had to transfer char encoding etc. while file handling. However, I was able to reproduce similar behavior without any encoding-related issues as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/32752318
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df1.to_csv('foo.csv', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')

df1.to_csv('bar.csv', index=True)
df3 = pd.read_csv('bar.csv')

print(df1.equals(df2), df1.equals(df3), df2.equals(df3))

print(all(df1 == df2))
```

Why does `.equals()` tell that the DataFrames differ, but `all(df1 == df2)` tells they are equal? According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html), `.equals()` even considers `NaN`s at same locations to be equal, whereas `df1 == df2` should not. Due to this, comparing different DataFrames with `.equals()` is less strict than `df1 == df2`, but does not return the same result in the example I provided.

Which criteria do `df1 == df2` and `df1.equals(df2)` consider I am not aware of? I assume, that the implementation inside pandas is correct (did not look into the implementation inside the code itself, but export and re-import should be a standard interface test case). What am I doing wrong then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `df1.equals(df2)` return `False` because it takes into account the `DataFrame` `dtype`. `df1` should have `int32` columns, while `df2` should have `int64` columns (you can use the `info()` method to verify it).
You can specify the `df2` `dtype` as follow in order to have the same `dtype` of `df1`:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', dtype=np.int32)
```

if `dtype` is the same, `.equals()` should return `True`

Answer (score 0):

When you write dataframe to .csv format with `index=True` ; it adds up extra column with name `Unnamed: 0`. That's why both `.equals()` and `all(df1 == df2)` tells dataframes are different. But, if you write .csv with `index=False` it will not add up an extra column and you will get output .csv equal to input dataframe.
If you don't care about dataframe index you can set `index=False` while writing dataframe to .csv or use `pd.read_csv('bar.csv').drop(['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1)` while reading csv.