# Add a vector/column of random numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've been trying to create a table that has randomly generated data using Pandas and Numpy. I've looked at the cheat sheet for Pandas but still can't get this work

```
import names
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(100)
currency_numbers = random.sample(range(100000, 1000000), 100)

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
raw_data = {

    "Names":["".join(names.get_full_name()) for i in range(100)],

    "Names2":["".join(names.get_full_name()) for i in range(100)],

    "Currency":[]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=["Names", "Names2", "Currency"])

df.head()
```

I want to create a column of 100 random numbers under the Currency section?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 100, size=(10,1)))` does what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a data frame of random integers with Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752292/how-to-create-a-data-frame-of-random-integers-with-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the function: **np.random.randint()**

For example when I call this --> np.random.randint(1000,size=100)

The largest integer to be chosen in the random function is 999 aka anything from [0, 1000) and the size of the array would have a length of 100.

Therefore in your case,

```
s = np.random.randint(1000,size=100)
```

then set Currency to s,

```
"Currency":s
```

and the resulting DataFrame should give a column with 100 random numbers

JUST FYI, with this function you can also set a low and a high range...
So in your case it would be something like this:

```
s = np.random.randint(100000, 1000000,size=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this helps.

```
import names
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(100)
currency_numbers = np.random.randint(100000,1000000,size=(1,100))

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
raw_data = {

    "Names":["".join(names.get_full_name()) for i in range(100)],

    "Names2":["".join(names.get_full_name()) for i in range(100)],

    "Currency":currency_numbers[0]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=["Names", "Names2", "Currency"])

df.head()
```