# How to iterate over a specific column in a already existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column to the dataframe that will create a unique random number between 15 and 33.

i have tried this:

```
import random
df[new_col] = random.randint(15,33)
```

The problem with this code is that it creates one random number and distribute in all the columns, whereas I want each row to have its unique random number.

I think I should use a for loop but kinda don't know how to start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a DataFrame of random integers with Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752292/how-to-create-a-dataframe-of-random-integers-with-pandas)

Comment: @Junkrat, This is not working. I implemented it in my code and it throws an a typ error. import random
import numpy as np

ride_sharing['tyre_size_2'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(15,33, size=(25760,1)), columns='tyre_size_2')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use apply function:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda s: random.randint(15,33),axis=1)
```