# plot graphs horizontally when using df.groupby.plot.bar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I want to graph 3 plots horizontally side by side

Three graphs are generated using the code below:

```
df.groupby(df.col1, pd.cut[0,1,2]).col2.mean().plot.bar()
df1.groupby(df.col1, pd.cut[0,1,2]).col2.mean().plot.bar()
df2.groupby(df.col1, pd.cut[0,1,2]).col2.mean().plot.bar()
```

I'm not sure where to set axes in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use pandas' [barh](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html) function.

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.col1, [0,1,2]).col2.mean().plot.barh()
```

This is an example, using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32752318/6440589) to create a dataframe with random samples:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.A, [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])).A.mean().plot.barh()
```

This snippet outputs the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I actually meants having 3 graphs, and display those horizontally side by side. Just edited the question to make it more clear