# Python 3 range Vs Python 2 range

Tags: python, list, range

I recently started learning python 3.
In **python 2** the `range()` function can be used to assign list elements:

```
>>> A = []
>>> A = range(0,6)
>>> print A
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But in **python 3** the `range()` function outputs this:

```
>>> A = []
>>> A = range(0,6)
>>> print(A)
range(0, 6)
```

Why is this happening?
Why did python do this change?
Is it a boon or a bane?

Comment: In Python-3.x, `range(..)` no longer produces a list, it produces a range object, that allows iteration, but also fast `len(..)`, `in` checks, etc.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3) and its answers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Python 3** uses *iterators* for a lot of things where **python 2** used *lists*.The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) give a detailed explanation including the change to `range`.

The advantage is that **Python 3** doesn't need to allocate the memory if you're using a large range iterator or mapping.
For example

```
for i in range(1000000000): print(i)
```

requires a lot less memory in python 3.
If you do happen to want Python to expand out the list all at once you can

```
list_of_range = list(range(10))
```

Answer (score 4):

in python 2, `range` is a built-in function. below is from [the official python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). it returns a list.

> **range**(stop)
>   **range**(start, stop[, step])
>   This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for loops.

also you may check [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) only existing in python 2. it returns `xrange` object, mainly for fast iteration.

> **xrange**(stop)
>   **xrange**(start, stop[, step])
>   This function is very similar to range(), but returns an xrange object instead of a list.

by the way, python 3 merges these two into one `range` data type, working in a similar way of `xrange` in python 2. check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#range).

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 `range()` function is equivalent to python 2 `xrange()` function not `range()`

Explanation

In python 3 most function return Iterable objects not lists as in python 2 in order to save memory. Some of those are `zip()` `filter()` `map()` including .`keys .values .items()` dictionary methods
But iterable objects are not efficient if your trying to iterate several times so you can still use `list()` method to convert them to lists

Answer (score 1):

In python3, do

```
A = range(0,6)
A = list(A)
print(A)
```

You will get the same result.

Comment: The question asks a lot more than how to get the python2 behavior

Comment: This helps a lot as well! Thanks for sharing.