# Need guidance in understanding how range or range() can be described in so many ways

Tags: python, function, range, operators, generator

I am very, very new to programming and am starting with Python. I am about thirty videos into a popular online course. In the most recent tutorial, the instructor introduces range [for example, range(0,10,1)]. In a just a few minutes, the tutor refers to range or range() as:

- an operator
- a function
- a keyword
- a generator

Range is also, as it turns out, within the Sequence data type, and I suppose it can also be called an 'object', right? I understand that the same "thing" can be described in different ways depending on the context. For example, it's no contradiction to say that I am both a Canadian and a husband. The problem is to keep all these categories straight in my head when trying to understand the role or state of a given term in Python. Is there some rubric or chart or method or set of definitions to understanding all the roles that a given "thing" plays in Python? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Never heard of range as an operator and I don't think is a keyword. Is true that it is a function and hence and object, because all functions are objects in Python

Comment: It's not an operator or keyword.

Comment: `range` is a class that implements the iterator protocol.

Comment: In Python 2 `range` was a function that returned a list, but as someone new to Python, that's just a piece of historical trivia, not something you need to worry about unless you are porting or maintaining older code.

Comment: Something you might find helpful are the [docs for operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) and [the docs for kewords](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html). For example, the operator docs list all operators and define what they are. Keyword has functions like `import keyword; keyword.iskeyword(range)` or the attribute `keyword.kwlist` which can help you test for yourself

Comment: `range` in Python 3.x isn't even a generator in the usual sense because it can be indexed and consumed repeatedly, which generators typically cannot be.

Comment: @sj95126 It's a "generator", just not a `generator`. `range` is an *iterable*, and implements `__iter__` by returning a *new* instance of `range_iterator` (that is, like all *iterators*, consumable only once) each time it is called.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone for these helpful answers, and for being patient with a newbie!

Comment: Could I then clarify the following: Would I be correct to say that the input below is a range function, while the output is a range instance of a Sequence data type?  
In:  
range(0,5,1)  
Out:   
0  
1   
2   
3   
4   
    
Thanks!

Comment: `range(0,5,1)` is you _instantiating a range object_ , or creating a new object of the `range` type.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than just answering what `range()` is, below is an attempt at showing how to investigate what something is or isn't in python. We can check two things at each step, the abstract `range`, and your initial example assigned to a variable (q is a terrible variable name but useful for brevity):

```
q=range(0,10,1)
```

We can also import some help with checking for [types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) and [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html):

```
import types
import keyword
```

Now, let's look at your proposed options for "what is it"?

##### an operator

In python, built-in operators "perform object comparisons, logical operations, mathematical operations and sequence operations" (From [the operator module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) ) You can see a long list of operators in the link provided, and `range()` isn't there.

##### a function (or method)

This is one of the more confusing ones at first glance, since googling "python range function" gives thousands of very authoritative hits. Also,  range is even listed in the documentation for built-in functions. That said, it's not a function according to those same docs: "class range(start, stop [,step])". We can test this as below, using one of our earlier imports and the pythonic method for checking whether something is what you think it is, `isinstance()`:

```
isinstance(range, types.FunctionType)
False
isinstance(q, types.FunctionType)
False

isinstance(range, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
False
isinstance(q, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
False

isinstance(range, types.BuiltinMethodType)
False
isinstance(q, types.BuiltinMethodType)
False
```

##### a keyword

Thankfully, this is much more straightforward.

```
import keyword
keyword.iskeyword(range)
False
```

You can also use `print(keyword.kwlist)` to see a list of all the keywords in python

##### a generator

As mentioned in the comments, while `range()` does *generate* something, it isn't a `generator` type object in python. Let's double check:

```
isinstance(range, types.GeneratorType)
False
isinstance(q, types.GeneratorType)
False
```

Now we can look at some other options, starting with [the docs for range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) to get an authoritative answer: "The range *type* represents an immutable sequence of numbers..."

Understandably, this is accurate but hard to parse for someone first learning. The simplest way to check what type an object is (besides using `types` and `isinstance`) is to just check the `type()`. Which gives the charming tautological definition, for example:

```
type(type)
type
```

So what is `range`, and what is an instance of a range?

```
type(range)
type

type(q)
range
```

And, to finish off the last part of your question, is it an object?
Everything in python is an object.

```
isinstance(q, object)
True
```

So, from the above, we can deduce that the answer to "what is a range in python?" is: Range is a type, and a defined range is an instance of an `object` of the `range` `type`

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you so much!  
(I do not yet have upvote privileges, or I would.)

Comment: Cheers, thanks for asking the question to begin with, there were several things even I didn't understand about range that this taught me! If this helped you out, you can use the green check mark to accept the answer

Comment: Done! Thanks again. 

Comment: And, not to overburden the point, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571718/python-3-range-vs-python-2-range) has some interesting discussion about the change from range being a function in python 2 to being it's own type in python 3 (probably a good portion of why it's still referred to as a function even though it no longer is)

Comment: Oh, that's a really good point.