# Drawing a random sample from a very large dataset

Tags: pandas, random, sample

I have a csv dataset with 160MM rows that is not possible to import directly through Pandas (RAM memory is not enough).
How could I draw a random sample of 5% from the original dataset (in this case, a sample with roughly 8MM rows)???
Amy insight is appreciated...
Cheers,
Marcelo

I have tried using chunks, but it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

1. Determine the total rows N in the CSV.  Maybe you already know.  You only need to do this once, you can store it somewhere for repeated use.
2. Generate random numbers in [0, N).  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77513347/4323
3. Sort the random numbers.
4. Read the CSV in a single pass.  For each random number, skip lines until you reach that row.  For faster line skipping, see [Skip first couple of lines while reading lines in Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578580/skip-first-couple-of-lines-while-reading-lines-in-python-file)

If that's not fast enough, here's another approach:

```
sample = subprocess.check_output(['shuf', '-n', '8000000', 'file.csv'])
```

It uses https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shuf.1.html which is probably faster than what you'll end up with in Python alone.